# How to set the class of an Ember component based data in the model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-components

I'm trying to setup the class name for the component which based on the data property. I succesfully set data to the template.hbs and I see that component is rendered. But inside the component.js I can't set the classname

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['complete:completed'],
  complete: Ember.computed('isCompleted', function(){
    return this.get('isCompleted');
  })
});
```

This is not working. Class name doesn't calculated. How can I do this?

This is my route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      todoList: this.store.findAll('todo')
    });
  }
});
```

and template.hbs

```
{{#each todoList as |todo|}}
  {{todo-item todo=todo}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but just a couple of notes. (1) You have properties and classes `completed`, `isCompleted`, and `complete`. Do yourself a favor and maintain your sanity by being as consistent as possible. (2) There no reason to return a single-element hash from the `model` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['todo.isCompleted:completed']
});
```

Comment: Yep. It work's. Thanks a lot :) This is realy very easy, Strange that I didn't find this way in the documentation